# How to rewrite an char array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, overwrite

I've searched around for a quiet some time but surprisingly I couldn't find an answer to it:

I want to rewrite a char array starting from [0], but all what's happening is: it's always appending. Here's my code:

The algorithm is: I have a very long string which I like to break into several lines (wherever there is a blank space at the end of a line). Each line shall be saved in an array Index (`lineContent`);

```
void print_text(char* content, int menu_width, int which_selected, int menu_height, int scroll_pos)
{
    int posCounter = 0;
    int charCounter = menu_width-10;
    int printOutCounter;

    char* lineContent[400]; // 400 lines max

    short spaceFound;

    while (strlen(content) > menu_width) // If string is longer than 1 line
    {
        //Interesting Part ---------- START

        char changeString [strlen(content)];
        char printString [menu_width-10];
        spaceFound = 0;
        charCounter = menu_width-10;
        lineContent[posCounter] = malloc(MAXITEMSTR);


        while (spaceFound == 0)
        {
            if (content[charCounter] == ' ')
            {
                // I guess the error goes between here ...
                strncpy(changeString,content,strlen(content));
                strncpy(printString,content,menu_width-10);
                // ...and here
                memmove(&changeString[0], &changeString[charCounter], strlen(content));
                content=changeString;
                lineContent[posCounter]=printString;
                strcat(lineContent[posCounter],"\0");
                posCounter++;
                spaceFound = 1;

                //Interesting Part ---------- END
            }

            charCounter--;

            if (charCounter <= 0)
                spaceFound = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, in the end, when checking the content of `lineContent`, every entry is the same (the one from the last line).

I think this is because, `strcpy` just appends to the end, therefor I have to clear the array, to erase the former line. So it will start from [0] and not from the last printed letter.

Has anybody an idea how to do this? Is there a function that overwrites a char array instead of appending it?

Kind Regards

Comment: strcat appends to the end, strcpy overwrites the value stored in the string.

Comment: (One version of your code had `if (strlen(content) > menu_width) { while (strlen(content) > menu_width) { … } }`; you can use just the loop rather than both the conditional and the loop. This is now fixed.)

Comment: `lineContent[posCounter]=printString;` is wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that's it - thanks I think it's time for leaving the code for today ;) - after using `strcpy` at this line too. everything works fine now.

Comment: You should use strdup instead for this case.

Comment: @Igor if you would make this as an aswer I'd accept it - to close this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Strcat` appends to the end, `strcpy` overwrites the value stored in the string.